# How to integrate large picture in remote notification in ios device

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, apn

How to integrate large picture in remote notification in ios device. In android we can use [Notification.BigPictureStyle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.BigPictureStyle.html) but in ios how can I implement that?

Comment: So large picture style not supported in ios ?

Comment: Sorry, massive typo there. The only image on an iOS notification is the application icon. It has a fixed size.

Comment: did you see such large icons on iOS notifications ever?